# Virtual destructor moves object out of rodata section

Tags: c++, gcc, elf

I have a large number of static constant objects which are constructed with a constexpr constructor, so they are immediately stored in the final binary without any constructor call.

Since I'm working on a low RAM system (STM32 MCU), I want to reduce the memory footprint of these objects and since they are constant, store them in the `.rodata` section instead. The compiler managed this without a problem.

But, now that I added a virtual destructor to the base class in order to remove compiler warnings, the objects are stored in the `.data` section instead.

Of course, I could use some `#pragma` to remove the compiler warnings for the base class specifically and remove the virtual destructor, but I want to know if there is a cleaner solution to this.

Minimalism code showcasing the problem:

```cpp
class Object {
    int value;
public:
    constexpr Object(int param) 
    : value(param) {}

    virtual int getValue() const = 0;

    virtual ~Object() = default; // This line causes problems
};

class Derived : public Object {
    volatile int otherValue;
public:
    constexpr Derived(int param1, int param2) 
    : Object(param1), otherValue(param2) {}

    int getValue() const override { return otherValue; }
};


const Derived instance(1,2);

int main() {
    return instance.getValue();
}
```

Also, here is a CompilerExplorer to compare with and without the virtual destructor: https://godbolt.org/z/M5G7LO

Comment: Classes with virtual 'functionality need vtable. Also virtual destructors are actually pairs. One of them calls delete() after destroying the object while the other don't. You can read [this](https://www.martinkysel.com/demystifying-virtual-tables-in-c-part-3-virtual-tables/) It may helps

Comment: I would avoid dynamic dispatching at all costs if programming a low-cost MCU...

Comment: What does `volatile` have to do with this?

Comment: To prevent the compiler from optimising the call to getValue() in the main body

Comment: I suggest using `-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor` instead of `-Wnon-virtual-dtor`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The moment you declare a virtual method, you add a non-constant pointer to your class that points to the virtual table of that class. This pointer will first be initialized to Object's virtual table, and then continue to change to the derived classes' virtual pointers throughout the constructor chain. It will then change again during the destructor chain and roll-back until it points to Object's virtual table.
That would mean that your object can no longer be a pure read-only object and must move out of .rodata.

A cleaner solution would either be to omit any virtual function in your classes, or to avoid inheritence entirely and use templates to replace the required virtual function calls with compile time calls.

Comment: would you mind adding an example? How to replace virtual with compile time system call using templates?

Comment: By using template specialization, which is basically function overloading with a fallback. Instead of saying instance.getValue(), you do getValue(instance) and the appropriate getValue function gets called.
But fundamentally, the issue is that you can't have virtual methods, so you need to change it to something that can be resolved at compile time. And if that is possible, there was no reason to use virtual in the first place. So to give proper advice, we need to understand why you are using virtual in the first place...

Answer (score 3):

For classes having virtual methods, compiler has to define vtables for each class in order to dynamically dispatch virtual method calls based on the type the object has. So, every objects of such classes have a hidden pointer to their types' vtable. This pointer is added to the class by the compiler and isn't `const` and changes throughout ctor and dtor call chain, so your `instance` isn't `const` and can't be in `.rodata`.

An [example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ANqI7ukSm1HxQq6i) demonstrating access to virtual methods through pointer to vtable.

```
#include <iostream>

class FooBar {
public:
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; };
    virtual void bar() { std::cout << "bar" << std::endl; };
};

int main()
{
    FooBar obj;
    // first bytes of 'obj' is a pointer to vtable
    uintptr_t vtable_ptr = ((uintptr_t*)&obj)[0];
    // 'foo' is at index '0' and 'bar' is at index '1'
    uintptr_t method_ptr = ((uintptr_t*)vtable_ptr)[1];
    // cast it to member pointer
    void (*func)(FooBar*) = (void (*)(FooBar*))method_ptr;
    // invoke the member function on 'obj'
    (*func)(&obj);
    return 0;
}
```

This code only works with particular compilers. Also note that the standard doesn't specify the implementation details of vtables, pointers to them and where they're stored, etc.